# Google Calendar won't sync after update on 9.2.1

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, google-calendar

I have recently updated to iOS 9.2.1, and now my Google Calendar isn't syncing anymore. If I add event on my desktop (Google Calendar App inside my browser), events are added and synced to my iPhone, but if I add event inside my Calendar app on iPhone, events are never synced to my Google Calendar, they only exists on my iPhone.

I have tried to restart phone, and reset network settings, but without luck.

EDIT: I have also noticed red exclamation sign on iCloud calendars, maybe is this issue?

[image]I

Answer (score 1):

Guess it has something to do with latest iOS update, removing account(s) which have shared calendars solve my problem.